# Server call after 3 character s are entered in typeahead

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Server call is made from jquery for a typeahead text box using **ajaxChosen** method, now we need to invoke server method only after 3 characters are inserted into the textbox but it is not working using mintermLenth

```
$("#test").ajaxChosen({
    minTermLength:3,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: $('#test').attr("typeahead")},{
        processItems: function (data) {
            return _.map(data, function (v) { return { id: v.Value, text: v.Text } }) 
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you declaring typeahead like `$('#test').typeahead()`? If yes, try setting minimum length e.g. `$('#test').typeahead({ minLength: 3 })`.

Comment: yes have used that as well, it does not solve the issue

Comment: Are you want to handle typeahead's textbox `keyup` event in such a way that after 3 keystrokes (exactly 3 characters) then `ajaxChosen` call will be triggered? Or maybe something else?

Comment: yes, that is what we are looking for.

Comment: Can you provide the textbox markup with `typeahead` definition? I think `keyup` event may be useful here besides `minTermLength` by checking amount of characters already typed inside typeahead textbox.

Comment: oh this worked `$('#test').typeahead({ min: 3 })`

Comment: I didn't see `min` usage, only `minLength` exists in this documentation: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md.

Comment: yea even i had seen that as well, but tried this to check and it worked. Not sure if its meant to work like this or a bug!